# No matching distribution found while using pip

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, ubuntu-18.04, pybossa

I've been trying to install **Pybossa** and I've been trying to follow these [steps](https://docs.pybossa.com/installation/guide/) from the documentation, and this [link](https://www.it.iitb.ac.in/frg/wiki/index.php?title=Open_Source_Crowd_Sourcing_Platforms&action=edit) too (which they're the same).

when it comes to using this command `pip install -r requirements.txt` it keeps running some installations and then and error occurred :

**ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jeepney==0.4 (from pybossa==3.1.2->-r requirements.t
xt (line 3)) (from versions: none)**

**ERROR: No matching distribution found for jeepney==0.4 (from pybossa==3.1.2->-r requirements.txt (line 3))**

this is what's inside requirements.txt : [image]

I don't know why this is happening as i'm following the documentation .. so i'd glade if anyone helped me.

I'm using :

- Ubuntu server 18.04
- python 2.7
- virtualenv
- PostgreSQL

Comment: maybe check `pip search jeepney` and install manually existing version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are better off going for **latest** python 3. python 2 had its [eol](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/) early this year. For new approaches it would be a dead end.

### I am on 16.04, but hope you can do the turn likewise

- make use of native venv option, don't use virtualenv any more
- during the setup you likely will get compilation errors. Those are due to the fact not having a fully equipped build machine. It's very likely that you need to `apt-get install` more or less dev packages to your system. It depends how deep you had done gcc compilation in the past. For me it was:

  - `sudo apt-get install python3-dev`
  - `sudo apt-get install libsasl2-dev libldap2-dev libssl-devm`
- whenever you encounter compilation errors like this:

  ```
  Modules/constants.h:7:18: fatal error: lber.h: No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.
  ```

  you need to find the appropriate dev lib and add it to the system with `apt-get` like mentioned above by easiest looking the error up in your favorite internet search engine

### Steps for the setup of pybossa

- `python3 -m venv ./pb_env`
- `. ./pb_env/bin/activate`
- `pip install --upgrade pip`
- `mkdir pb #shorthand for pybossa`
- `cd pb`
- `git clone --recursive https://github.com/Scifabric/pybossa`
- `cd pybossa/`
- `pip install -r requirements.txt`

feel free to ask again if you still get stuck.

Comment: Thank you. This worked fine, ,but i got stuck further while i'm trying to populate the databases.

Comment: ,So i went for -Create a settings file and enter your SQLAlchemy DB URI `cp settings_local.py.tmpl settings_local.py`, -Create the alembic config file and set the sqlalchemy.url to point to your database `cp alembic.ini.template alembic.ini`, -To run redis sudo `apt-get install redis-server`, -Then configure data base and create DB all these have worked fine, `but i stuck at Populate the database with its tables `python cli.py db_create`

Comment: It looks like you are trying to install over an previus likely failed shot. `psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "category_name_key"
DETAIL:  Key (name)=(Thinking) already exists`
Maybe you can try to empty all your tables, then start over

Comment: I've dropped all the tables, and run the command again and i got this as an output https://textuploader.com/1mkxv!   `i don't know if this mean a success or not`

Comment: I've tried to see if this is correct or not, by connecting to the DB and see if the tables have been created or not, and i found them. so i assumed it worked :D, then i tried to run the web server through python run.py and connect to http://(IP):5000 but i always got This site can’t be reached (IP) took too long to respond.

Comment: As a test I would recommend to run your service on localhost, which is `127.0.0.1:5000`. My assumption is that if you secretly hide the IP, you try to connect to outside of the world. If I am wrong and you really need to connect to the outside world, you could try to ping your secret ip, to see whether the link is up at least. But that does not ensure the service is up. It anyway somehow doesn't fit together, if you install all your stuff locally and then go for testing outside of your home or even your machine. In real scenario it could truly be to go outside for super duper calc power

Comment: I've already tried to connect using 127.0.0.1:5000, but it say the same `This site can’t be reached 127.0.0.1 refused to connect.`  and as the IP i'm trying to connect to it's the server ip not a big secret tho! it's 35.188.220.179. I tried to ping it too and everything is fine.  I'm trying to setup pybossa installation on Ubuntu server instance on GCP that's all.

Comment: It's not enough to just point your browser to `127.0.0.1:5000`. You also need to start your web-service onto this resource.

Comment: and this what i get when i run `python run.py`  https://textuploader.com/1mkv0

Comment: sorry but i didn't understand what do you mean by start my web-service onto this resource?

Comment: Then try to point your browser to `http://0.0.0.0:5000/`. And you should see some response from your local service

Comment: The webpage at http://0.0.0.0:5000/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

Answer (score 0):

All versions of jeepney starting with 0.1 (released in 2017) requires Python >= 3.5.